# Event.watch gets fired infinitely many times

Tags: web3js, bug, truffle

I am trying out truffle + web3 + ethereumjs-testrpc. In the app I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();
  var event = meta.Transfer({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

and I am getting the latest transfer endlessly in console. 
The contract is standard MetaCoin with an event Transfer added. [Here](https://gist.github.com/leitasat/47ae45a0633b4ab0bc833aa631160227) is the full code.

Comment: okay, I have tried with testnet at geth and it worked properly (each event got logged once) so it is a testrpc issue.

Comment: more precise bug report: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/56#issuecomment-205653571

Comment: If it's a bug, feel free to answer your own question with a link to the related bug tracker issue.

Answer (score 4):

This bug was apparently due to the fact that:

> After calling `eth_getFilterChanges` testrpc reports the events, and forgets that it reported it for current block, so when the next `eth_getFilterChanges` happens, testrpc reports the same events again, and again, infinitely, until the new transaction(block) happens, then it starts reporting the event from new latest block endlessly.

It only occurred in testrpc, not geth.

The bug was fixed by tcoulter in v2.0.3 and should no longer be an issue.